# How to activate super+scroll to zoom?

Tags: 11.04, compiz, zooming

In maverick, and I belive many old ubuntus, one could zoom in and out by holding super and scrolling with the mouse, but that doesn't work in Natty. How do you activate that again?

Comment: This has me puzzled too...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First of all you need to install [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) from the Software Centre. Once you've done that then launch it, and find the *Enhanced Zoom Desktop* plugin.

Here you need to enable the Zoom In and Zoom Out mouse shortcuts. To get the same behaviour as in 10.10 then set Zoom In to Button4 and Zoom Out to Button5.

Be aware that [the Unity panel and launcher are not zoomable](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/762699) (this is probably why this functionality was disabled by default). Also [the panel shadow may get in the way](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/762247).

[image: Screenshot of changing settings]

Comment: For the "panel shadow may get in the way." use shift instead of super button :D

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed in a million years that Button 4 and 5 are the scroll wheel. And I'm a developer!

Answer (score 0):

Works in 11.10 also. http://jdnash.com/2012/02/practical-ubuntu-part-2-of-2/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.