# How do you zoom in Ubuntu Natty?

Tags: 11.04, zooming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to activate super+scroll to zoom?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36751/how-to-activate-superscroll-to-zoom)

Before update my Ubuntu to Natty, I zoomed in-out the screen using the Winkey + mouse wheel.

Now, how can in zoom in-out with Natty?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah I hit this too. You just need put the settings back into Compiz.

1. Download CCSM. Either search the software centre or pump this into a terminal.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Run it. Whack `ccsm` into a run dialogue.
3. Under the "Enhanced Zoom Desktop" plugin, look at the "Zoom In/Out" tab. You want to alter the gestures so that you have something like the following:

   - Zoom in: `<Super>Button4`
   - Zoom out: `<Super>Button5`
   - Zoom box: `<Super>Button2`

That should return things to how they were. You should have a look at the other tabs too because they have improved some of the features. I've fallen for the panning mode.