# Zoom in/out by mouse wheel with compaz doesn't work

Tags: compiz

I want to use zoom in and zoom out function by `alt` + mouse wheel.

[How to activate super+scroll to zoom?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36751/how-to-activate-superscroll-to-zoom)

I configured according to this answer, but it doesn't work in my environment.

This is my config panel. `無効` means "invalid"

[image: CompizConfig]

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 in Virtualbox.

What can I do to enable zooming function?