# How to use MouseWheel to zoom Desktop on 16.04.02 Xenial

Tags: 16.04, unity, macbook-pro

[Macbook Pro 2014]
*Note that I'm running Xenial on a MacBook Pro Retina 2014*

I have the Tweak Tool installed, and on the "General" tab I can set keys to zoom my desktop in/out, but I am unable to make the Tweak Tool recognise the mousewheel.

While researching this question, I eventually found that CompizConfig is needed and that [the guide for Ubuntu 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36751/how-to-activate-superscroll-to-zoom) is still valid. (*Note that button 4 is mousewheel scroll up, and button 5 is scroll down.*)

It seems a bit silly that both Tweak Tool and CompizConfig allow control of the feature but only CompizConfig allows you to specify the mousewheel.  Is there a way to set this through the Tweak Tool?

Comment: Can't you just hold down the **Control** key whilst rolling your mousewheel to zoom in/out?

Comment: No, doesn't work.  I should have noted that I'm running Xenial on a MacBook Pro with rEFInd.

Comment: @heynnema, that's the same link I referred to in my OP.

Comment: If CompizConfig will do the job, I'm confused. Are you only asking if Tweak Tool can do the same job? Why? If you didn't find it there, then the answer must be no?